# ZF2 - loop the loop

Tags: frameworks, zend-framework2

In my model I have:

```
public function fetchForParentId($id)
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(array('acl_menu_parent_id' => $id));
    $resultSet->buffer();
    $resultSet->next();
    return $resultSet;
}
```

and controller:

```
$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $this->layout()->acl_menu = $sm->get('AdminSettings\Model\AclMenuTable');
```

In my View I can use model function:

```
<?php 
$rows = $this->acl_menu->fetchForParentId(0);
foreach ($rows as $item):
    echo $item->acl_menu_name.'<br>';
endforeach;
?>
```

It works, but if I try to run this:

```
<?php 
$rows = $this->acl_menu->fetchForParentId(0);
foreach ($rows as $item):
    echo $item->acl_menu_name.'<br>';
    $subRows = $this->acl_menu->fetchForParentId($item->acl_menu_id);
    foreach ($subRows as $subItem):
        echo ' - '.$subItem->acl_menu_name.'<br>';
    endforeach;
endforeach;
?>
```

Second foreach doesn't work, $rows->acl_menu_id exists and in database there are correct rows to show.

I do not know why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `$item` instead of `$rows`:

```
$subRows = $this->acl_menu->fetchForParentId($item->acl_menu_id);
```

Comment: ok, I rewrote second foreach and now is ok. Some whitespace ? It does'n matter. Thank you for your time.